# Why have there been a lot of old questions showing up on the front page on April 2nd?

Tags: support

I wonder why there have been a lot of old posts suddenly showing up on the front page on April 2nd? It's hard to find new questions among all these apparently unchanged old posts. What is going on here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We got hit by a massive flood of spam posts. The automated spam detector and the moderators are working on removing them, but they still bump up every question to the front page. To see new questions only, use the ["week" view](https://apple.stackexchange.com/?tab=week).

Also, if you still see answers looking like

> my name is NAME My private video, see URL

please flag them as spam so we can remove them.

Comment: I was wondering about that, thanks. I got 16 Autoflags yesterday.