# Why so many old questions at the top of the list -- and what to do with them?

Tags: discussion

I can understand that it's good to let low-scoring older questions bubble back to the surface, in case there is new information, or someone has a new angle: but there often seem to be a lot of very old questions on the front page of the site.

Often these just have "modified 16 mins Community", but I can never find what that edit might be. Is that just [spam removal](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3522/why-have-there-been-a-lot-of-old-questions-showing-up-on-the-front-page-on-april)?

Do old questions ever get 'archived'? (At what point do questions about OS X Panther become Retrocomputing?)

Do 'low-quality' questions-and-answers (e.g. someone never responds to a Q, and low scores all round) ever get pruned from the site?

I often start typing an answer and then realise it's about someone's hard drive 7 years ago. Yes, I suppose I could click on "Questions" instead.

And I can understand that some little nugget of info might be the very info needed by someone searching for answers.

I suppose I'm just thinking out loud that the 'signal-to-noise' is sometimes high. (Or is that low?)

Can we vote to close questions on grounds of being old and unimpressive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Bumps

The Community user bumps old questions to the front page occasionally. You can tell a question has been bumped because it will show in the

- revision history (`/posts/id/revisions`)

  [image]
- timeline (`/posts/id/timeline`)

  [image]

> - The Community user will bump non-negatively scored, open questions every hour that [have at least one answer scoring 0 and none scoring more than that](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184511/155074).
>
>   - Questions are [picked randomly from the top-viewed questions with last activity more than 30 days ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/99690).
>   - Once a question is bumped, it will be [ineligible for bumping for the next 120 days](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1374/was-there-a-change-to-the-community-bot-that-stops-it-from-bumping-questions/1375#1375), *unless* it receives new activity after the last bump. (Bumping a question counts as new activity, so at a given time, questions bumped within the last 30 days are guaranteed not to be bumped.)
>   - The maximum number of unanswered questions bumped per hour [is] 1 per hour [on] [all other sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184511).

[What can cause a question to be bumped?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/48578/222623)

### Deletions

Old questions don't get archived as they can still be valuable for people using older systems. The Community user does delete questions falling under a certain criteria, which you can see at [**/help/roomba**](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/roomba).

Comment: Thanks. Just one thing: how do you get to the 'timeline'? Presumably there's only 'revision history' if someone's made some edits?

Comment: @ben Added paths to the answer. The link to the revision history only shows when there’s been an edit, but you can still get to the page manually.